# Azure release pipeline, continue after failed stage

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have following azure release pipeline:

[image]

Problem is that I need to left left stage to fail sometimes, but at the same time, even if it failed, right stage should still be executed, is that possible?

The only thing I found was 'Trigger even when the selected stages partially succeed' but it does not work if previous stage FAILED.

[image]

Comment: You should consider "generating test report" as a last step of the first stage instead of another dependent stage.

Comment: I did initially, however my new requirement is that I need to split 'left' stage into multiple stages (running multiple tests in parallel) and once all of them are executed, 'generating test report' stage would generate joint report. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I need to left left stage to fail sometimes, but at the same time, even if it failed, right stage should still be executed, is that possible?

Yes, it's possible. Please follow below steps and see if it works for you:

First, enable "Trigger even when the selected stages partially succeed" for the right stage as you already did.
[image]

Then, enable "Continue on error" for the tasks or the specific task if you know which one would fail in "Control Options". This will force the task to continue even it met errors which makes that stage a partially succeeded one.
[image]

At last, you can run the release pipeline and see the right stage will be executed even the tasks in left stage failed.
[image]

Hope this would work for you.

Comment: Upvoted: 22 months later, I had the same problem, and verified this still works.