# Azure DevOps - Continue on Time out error in Pipeline Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

If azure deployment pipeline stages fails with time out error any options available to continue with next stage ? I have tried with few option like continue with error, partial error etc all work if error occurs not on timeout error

Thanks You

Comment: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564305/azure-release-pipeline-continue-after-failed-stage#:~:text=First%2C%20enable%20%22Trigger%20even%20when%20the%20selected%20stages,which%20makes%20that%20stage%20a%20partially%20succeeded%20one.

Answer (score 0):

For the stage trigger option : **Trigger even when the selected stages partially succeed**, it requires the previous stages partially succeed. If all the tasks of first stage are failed it won't trigger the second stage. It requires the first stage has at least one successful task.

[image]